# How to read doubles from a string in c++ using istringstream

Tags: c++, istringstream

I am new to programming c++. I am trying to read 75 doubles that are inside of a string that I read from a file. I am trying to use istringstream.

This is what I have so far:
Header File:

```
#ifndef READPOINTS_H_INCLUDE
#define READPOINTS_H_INCLUDE
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std::istringstream;
.....
istringstream linestr;
```

---

CPP FILE:
    #include

```
void ReadPoints::grabPoin(const string& read_line, vector<doubles> PointVector){

linestr(read_line);

for(int i = 0; i < 75; i++){

 linestr >> value

 pointVector.push_back(value);
 }
}
```

When I compile this code I get the following error:

ReadPoints.cpp: In member function ‘bool ReadPoints::grabPoint(const string&, std::vector&)’:
ReadPoints.cpp:48:19: error: no match for call to ‘(std::istringstream {aka std::basic_istringstream}) (const string&)’
  linestr(read_line);

Can anyone explain what is wrong and why I am getting the no match for call?

Comment: `istringstream ` does not have an `operator()`, so `linestr(read_line)` is illegal

Comment: Okay thank you, I used linestr.str(read_line); and it compiled.

Comment: Let's be clear. You don't have 'doubles in a string'. You have *real numbers* in a string, in ASCII, and you want to read, convert, and store them into double variables.

Comment: `std::istringstream` is not a namespace.

Comment: Re @EJP's comment, you don't even have numbers in your string. You have number specifications. Most probably they're pure ASCII.

Comment: Re `linestr(read_line);`, that's not a declaration, that's a call of a non-existent `operator()`. Instead use `std::istringstream linestr( read_line );`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't place a definition inside a header. Currently, you've got `istringstream linestr;`: place this in exactly one *.cpp file, and then in your header, `extern std::istringstream linestr` (the latter is called a declaration, which is different to a definition). However, this stringstream is best defined in the function itself anyway.

Replace `linestr(read_line)` in your *.cpp with `std::istringstream line_str{ read_line }` and remove these two lines from your header file: `using namespace std::istringstream;` and `istringstream linestr;`.

Your code should now look like this:

```
void ReadPoints::grabPoin(const string& read_line, vector<doubles> PointVector){

std::istringstream linestr{ read_line }; // if that doesn't work, use linestr(read_line) instead... note the () and {} have different meanings

for(int i = 0; i < 75; i++){

 linestr >> value

 pointVector.push_back(value);
 }
}
```

Here's a couple of other tips:

- Never place a using directive inside a header (that is, `using namespace`)
- Avoid using directives at all costs. If you don't want to type `std::istringstream`, place it inside your *.cpp files (yes, each of them), as `using std::istringstream`.
- If you must use a using directive, you need to do it like so: `using namespace std;`.

Both of these will help you to avoid namespace pollution, which makes calling the right functions difficult.